# Spring validation issue

Tags: spring, introspection, ibm-jdk

We are facing an issue in IBM RAD IDE environment (IBM JDK 1.6 as the runtime JRE) while executing a test case. The same code is running fine with Springsource IDE (Sun JDK 1.6 as the runtime JRE). Is it an issue with JDK or with Spring framework.
Brief code history : 
There is a java bean as below

```
class User {
             final Map<Integer,String> securityQuestions = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer,String>(MAX_SECURITY_QUESTIONS));
            final Map<Integer,String> securityAnswers = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer,String>(MAX_SECURITY_QUESTIONS));

      public Map<Integer,String> getSecurityAnswers() {
            return securityAnswers;
        }

    public void setSecurityAnswer(Integer answerNumber, String answerText) {
            securityAnswers.put(answerNumber, answerText);
        }
   }
```

when we are trying to validate the 'securityAnswers'  using

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "securityAnswers", "seqQans.obj.required","security Question list cannot be empty");
```

we are getting this exception.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'securityAnswers' of bean class [User]: Bean property 'securityAnswers' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
      at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:705)
      at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:697)
      at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
      at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:226)
      at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(ValidationUtils.java:224)
      at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(ValidationUtils.java:182)

Comment: are you sure IBM RAD IDE environment has compiled User in place? I suspect it is missing updated User.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. can you elaborate on 'missing updated user'..

Comment: What I meant was, your RAD Runtime might not have compiled User class with securityAnswers. I would suggest do a complete cleanup and rebuild.

Comment: thanks. I am certain that he has compiled, because the same code works when deployed as an application IDM Websphere. However, in the RAD IDE, the test case reports this issue. I was wondering if this post is related..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849042/beanwrapperimpl-issues-only-with-websphere ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ! but I don't believe RAD has anything to do with this.The exception clearly states the reason why this is happening:

> Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer is no :)

Comment: thanks, but if this is a code level issue, we should get similar exception thrown for all tests. This works fine in my Springsource IDE. I am thinking that the getter method (readMethod()) is checked against and lenient with the setter method argument..

Comment: I think the issue is in SecurityAnswers getter and setter. Try changing the parameter of setSecurityAnswers to a map.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8806 https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8347 are both related to this issue I guess.. however, we can try have a same matching read and write method names

Comment: Yes do try, I think that should solve this issue pretty much.